# Use client to server MAC algorithm hmac-sha2-256 in ssh2_connect

Tags: php, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to connect to my SFTP server (prosftpd) but when I check its logs I find :

> 2018-04-19 11:00:48,303 mod_sftp/0.9.9[18488]: no shared client-to-server MAC algorithm found (client sent 'hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', server sent 'hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,umac-64@openssh.com')

I tried to use the "method" parameter:

```
ssh2_connect("my-sftp-server.com", 443, array(
    "client_to_server" => array(
      "mac" => 'hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,umac-64@openssh.com'
```

But it doesn't work, it seems like this algorithm is not supported by the method `ssh2_connect` and on my logs I can see

> client sent 'hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com'

Is there a way to install new MAC algorithm on my PHP SFTP client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP SSH2 package](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) uses [libssh2 library](https://libssh2.org/).

You need [libssh2 version 1.7.0](https://libssh2.org/changes.html#1.7.0) (2016-02-23) or later for `hmac-sha2-256` and `hmac-sha2-512`. There's no support for `umac-64@openssh.com`.

---

Alternatively, you can use [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), which supports `hmac-sha2-256` ever since [version 0.3.8](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#038---2014-09-12) (2014-09-12). There's no support for `hmac-sha2-512`, nor `umac-64@openssh.com`.